# Laravel Multi mysql DBs - login worked fine on Login controller - but after login Auth::user() showing data from 1st DB instead of login one

Tags: laravel, authentication, multiple-databases

i am using multi mysql DBs mysql, mysql2, mysql3 are the connection names.
at login it check the user and pass in all DB and login - dd(Auth::user()) shows proper user data as per respective DB in loginController just after auth()->attempt() lets say user from mysql2 named user2 - showing here

but when user if redirected to dashboard dd(Auth::user()) started to show data from 1st default connection DB lets say it user1 - but we login the user2

Note: the Auth::user() data is not proper - rest of the data is coming properly - the issue is with Auth::user() only

i tried to print dd(Auth::user()) in login controller showing proper data
in HomeController showing data from 1st DB instead of login one.

- i tried to change the default connection
- i tried to empty the default connection
- i tried all available methods on stackoverflow + laracasts
- Further i tried multiple guards and provider with proper db connection inside config.auth.defaults.guard

Note: DB user is same for all databases - phpmyadmin user

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell specifically without your code as this could happen due to multiple reasons. Ensure that you've properly set up multiple guards and provides in the following way:

```
'guards' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'mysql',
    ],
    'mysql2' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'mysql2',
    ],
    // Add more guards as needed
],

'providers' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'mysql2' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    // Add more providers as needed
],
```

Also ensure you're callling the proper guard when attempting to authenticate a user:

```
auth()->guard('mysql2')->attempt($credentials)
```

Also after authenticating set the appropriate database connection for the **auth** user session using the `setDefaultConnection` method from the `DB` facade. Do the same also when registering an user.

```
$connectionName = 'mysql2';
DB::setDefaultConnection($connectionName);
```

And finally try:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```